# SyntaxError when defining array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a program in python and when I debug my code I have some output like:

```
A = [[ 0.49184191  0.49216545  0.49045572  0.49120336  0.49162126  0.49127175
   0.4918312   0.49146007  0.49217111  0.49105725  0.49188209  0.49131341
   0.4915551   0.4916877   0.49176704  0.49107439  0.49179349  0.49113405
   0.49181949  0.49114229  0.49080868  0.49212299  0.49132733  0.49130678
   0.49243294  0.49138045  0.49142812  0.49110904  0.49057333  0.49152252
   0.49156431  0.49158843  0.49213234  0.49119104  0.49058275  0.49160299
   0.49096081  0.49144198  0.4920761   0.49149983  0.49164554  0.49108083
   0.49207692  0.49160705  0.49198164  0.49135187  0.49185721  0.49189228
   0.49173232  0.49141264  0.49135901  0.49203396  0.49211383  0.49157355
   0.49164756  0.4910949   0.49197874  0.49131     0.4915147   0.4912441
   0.49158387  0.49133532  0.49115916  0.49170297  0.49213771  0.49130702
   0.49181432  0.4913136   0.49129868  0.49137166  0.49195617  0.4911638
   0.4919901   0.49131729  0.49183565  0.49135328  0.49133418  0.49114096
   0.49153416  0.49129274  0.4915175   0.49140146  0.49147821  0.4923465
   0.49138114  0.49110974  0.49204106  0.49100999  0.49227227  0.49124463
   0.49178075  0.49126929  0.49129691  0.4916742   0.49099519  0.491607
   0.49153693  0.49128967  0.49183968  0.49183926  0.49191762  0.49191687
   0.49191334]]
```

and

```
Y = [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

And it seems no problem to execute some actions with those variables like eg:

```
dA = - (np.divide(Y, A) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A))
```

But when I define in a separate cell some arrays for my own use:

```
import numpy as np

m = [[4 5 6]]
n = [[1 2 3]]
```

Then as output I have:

```
File "<ipython-input-61-52c19e46fafb>", line 3
    m = [[4 5 6]]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So why is it not possible to define m and n as I have some output like that in my other Code?

Comment: The printed value is not necessarily equal to the actual stored value. Thus, assigning a value *exactly like* the printed value is not necessarily the right way to assign it

Answer (score 3):

When you debug your code, you or the debugger uses `print` to display NumPy arrays. The `print` command doesn't represent what you need to *define* an array. It applies specific display rules to aid presentation.

In this case, you need to make sure you use `,` to separate values in a NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([4, 5, 6])
n = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Is m = [[4, 5 , 6]] equal to [[4 5 6]]? If i do print ("m = " +str(m)) I have as result m = [[4, 5, 6]] and not [[4 5 6]] whereas in my code that I debug when I use the print comment print("A = " +str(A)) I have the result as above without any comma's ?

Comment: What do you see with `print(np.array([4, 5, 6]))` ?

Comment: what I have is [4 5 6]

Comment: @Ilse, Exactly, so you've demonstrated that the way you define an array to Python is different to what `print` displays. This is a purely display / presentation issue. You should not worry about the display (this is not something you control). Focus on the correct syntax, which means use commas.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of syntax vs. encoding vs. representation:

```
>>> print 1e3
1000.0
```

As one can see... this doesn't print `1e3`. It prints `1000.0`. But does that mean that `1e3` isn't equal to `1000.0`?

```
>>> print 1e3 == 1000.0
True
```

No. It's equal. So `1e3` and `1000.0` are *semantically* the same thing but look different syntactically.

```
>>> print "hi"
hi
```

but then:

```
>>> print hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hi' is not defined
```

`hi` and `"hi"` could be thought of as semantically identical but syntactically they mean completely different things. What print does is it prints out a "string version" of the object/value. It doesn't necessarily print it out the same way you enter it in code.

```
>>> class Animal:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return "Cat"
... 
>>> print Animal()
Cat
```

This prints `Cat` but we can't use `Cat` to create an animal.

Now, the syntax for lists in python requires commas. Also... numpy arrays ARE NOT lists. The have different types. Even if the string representation WERE the same: "5" and 5 have the same string representation but:

```
>>> print "5"
5
>>> print 5
5
```

Just because `str(a) == str(b)` doesn't mean imply that `a == b` nor does it imply `type(a) == type(b)`.

they are not even of the same type. One's an integer and the other's a string. If you define your own type you can define a string representation for your type but this doesn't change the syntax of the language.

What numpy does is something like this:

```
>>> class Array:
...   def __init__(self, xs):
...     self.xs = xs
...   def __str__(self):
...     return "[%s]" % (" ".join(map(str, self.xs)))
... 
>>> arr = Array([1,2,3])
>>> arr
<__main__.Array instance at 0x7f783f257ef0>
>>> print arr
[1 2 3]
```

It just defines a string representation. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to print it:

```
>>> class Array:
...   def __init__(self, xs):
...     self.xs = xs
... 
>>> arr = Array([1,2,3])
>>> print arr
<__main__.Array instance at 0x7f783f257f38>
```

However, we can't expect that when we enter a string representation of something into our code that it's valid code... because it's just a string representation of *something*... it's not necessarily valid code.